# Why do I get the error "ERROR running force:org:delete: this.org.getSandboxOrgConfigField is not a function" while deleting scrach-orgs

Tags: salesforcedx

#### The issue

When running `sfdx force:org:delete -u scrach-org-alias` I get the following error:

```
> sfdx force:org:delete -u myscratch
ERROR running force:org:delete:  this.org.getSandboxOrgConfigField is not a function
```

I only get the error when I use `sfdx force:org:delete` all the other commands works. I tried from both Cygwin and Powershell on a Windows 10 machine.

#### Questions

How do I fix the error?

Comment: i have this same issue. reinstalled vs code and extensions, still the same this. only in delete org that this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

Remove Salesforce CLI, download the latest version and install, run `sfdx update`.